# missing reference for kendo.data.ObservableObject when extending typescript class

Tags: kendo-ui, typescript, observable

```
export class MyClass extends kendo.data.ObservableObject {

constructor() {
        super();
        super.init(this);

    }

.
.
.
.


}
```

I get compilation error: 
Error   599 Build: Type name 'kendo.data.ObservableObject' in extends clause does not reference constructor function for 'kendo.data.ObservableObject'.

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 0):

> Type name 'kendo.data.ObservableObject' in extends clause does not reference constructor function for 'kendo.data.ObservableObject'.

Based on http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/framework/observableobject the constructor needs as least one argument (the object to observe) So you need to call the constructor with an argument as shown:

```
export class MyClass extends kendo.data.ObservableObject {

    constructor(objToObserve) {
        super(objToObserve);
    }

.
.
.
.


}
```

Answer (score 0):

This error, perhaps the most confusing issued by the compiler, means that when the compiler looked up the *value* indicated by the type in the extends clause, it didn't resolve to a value that was a constructor function for that type.

A smaller example:

```
class C { }

module M {
    var C = 3;
    class D extends C { } // <-- Error
}
```

Here, the *type name* `C` inside `M` means `class C`, but the *value name* `C` means the `var` declared in the module.

It sounds like you might have a `var kendo` or `var data` somewhere in your program. To diagnose this, above the line you write `extends kendo.data.ObservableObject`, write `var foo: kendo.data.ObservableObject` and see what error you get.